# Using RTF Templates with mergefields as input for generating reports

Tags: rtf, docx4j, mergefield

I have a requirement to generate word documents from j2EE/java where the input would be a RTF template (.rtf document) having merge fields.

I have looked at docx4j which accepts only docx as input. RTFTemplate which requires a template engine(not sure - documentation not very clear)

Could anyone please help with the options that are available. Both open and paid.

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0):

you can use net.sourceforge.rtf.RTFTemplate. It is open source.